# Methods to use materials with displacement other than adaptive subdivision?

Tags: texturing, materials, subdivision-surface, displacement

Are there any other ways to use displacement textures without using adaptive subdivision? Because it devours my entire VRAM each time I use it. Oftentimes it works when i turn up the dicing scale to 2px for example, but sometimes there is no more geometry that I can hide to make it work or the details get lost if i set the dicing scale any higher...